# Converting string coordinates into positions on an array in java

Tags: java

Hi was hoping for some help with the logic behind reading in values for a tic tac toe game I'm building.

Comment: It tells you that `row` might be uninitialized because if all `if`s  evaluate to `false`, `row` will be uninitialized. The fact that you tell the user to insert a letter between `a` and `c` will not make you sure that he won't enter `d`. In that case, `row` would stay uninitialized.

Comment: I see, is there a simple way around this?

Comment: should I put an else statement in their warning incorrect letter?

Comment: yes, you should, you can use a while loop to keep asking the user for a correct input

Comment: `string.equals('a')` will never be true, the parameter type must be string. Rewrite all those conditions like this: `string.equals("a")`

Comment: 'do  {  do 
             {
             System.out.printf("Player %s please enter an instruction (a-c): ", player);
             String string = instruction.next();
                     
             if (string.equals("a")  
              row = 0;
             if (string.equals("b"))  
              row = 1;
             if (string.equals("c"))  
              row = 2;
             else (System.out.printf("Incorrect letter has been inputted."));
             } while (row < 3 || row >= 0);

Comment: Would it be perhaps be easier to take away the ASCI value from the string I read in? I am new to Java but have spent a few months on c, so still discovering which bits are the same

Answer (score 1):

You have just to set a default value at start like :

```
int row = 0, column;
```

Or write another whileLoop to prevent this

---

Next to that, there is easier way for your assignement of `row` (and be careful car you compare a `String` to a `char`, on my computer it didn't work ):

**1.** Compare the first letter of the answer (or `.equals("a")`):

```
if (string.charAt(0)=='a')
    row = 0;
if (string.charAt(0)=='b')
    row = 1;
if (string.charAt(0)=='c')
    row = 2;
```

**2.** Make a switch case because you compare always the same thing :

```
switch(string.charAt(0)){
        case 'a':
            row=0;
            break;
        case 'b':
            row=1;
            break;
        case 'c':
            row=2;
            break;
        }
```

**3.** Use their ASCII value :

```
row = string.charAt(0)-97;
```

---

So :

```
public void askPlayer(char player) {
        Scanner instruction = new Scanner(System.in);
        int row, column;
        do {
            System.out.printf("Player %s please enter an instruction (a-c): ", player);
            String string = instruction.next();
            row = string.charAt(0)-97;
            System.out.printf("Player %s please enter a column (1-3): ", player);
            column = instruction.nextInt();
        } while (!inBounds(row, column));
         makeMove(player, row, column - 1);
    } // end of ask player method
```

And be careful because if your `inBounds()` is well-implemented : ***it will return true if the coordinates are correct*** but the while loop will continue if the condition is true and you need that it loops when coordinates are NOT correct, so you need to have `!inBounds()`

Comment: Great thanks, yeah I also just thought minusing the ASCI value was the cleanest way of doing it.  One this I am slightly confused  by is the Charat(0) - how will the programme know what the 0 value is?

Comment: The .charAt() method will use the String like an array, so it has many index and each element at a given index is one char. So '0' will be the first index -> first char
You have also char[] tab =  string.toCharArray() and here is will create the array, so .charAt() is shortcut to .toCharArray() and then acces to it

Comment: I see, the code isn't working and I don't think the value is being stored. Would i need to convert it from a string to an int? after taking away the 97 value

Comment: No, because when you use mathematical functions on a char it use directly its ascii value, so it's okay it goes in an int
Write a System.out.println("-> "+row"; after your while loop to check, and where is exactly the problem ?

Comment: `row = string.charAt(0)-97;` can also be re-written as `row = string.charAt(0) - 'a'` for clarity purposes :)

Comment: yep works fine, thanks all. Cheers Backslash, your way is clearer indeed.